# How to get returned values from my listener's callback ES6 way

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener

I made an input that let me filter a table of softwares.

```
<input type="text" id="softwares-search" class="form-control" aria-label="Input de recherche" aria-describedby="softwares-search">
```

Then in javascript my filter work well if I `console.log(....)`
But when I replace it with a return, nothing is returned. I think it is due to my var affectation through the event listener :

```
const maxwell = () => {
  search = document.querySelector('#softwares-search').value;
  return softwares.filter(row => row.name.includes(search) || row.description.includes(search));
}

const softwaresSearch = document.querySelector('#softwares-search');
if (softwaresSearch) {
  var results = softwaresSearch.addEventListener('keyup', maxwell)
  console.log(results);
}
```

Thank all

EDIT 1 :

I was so angry, so blind, I had S#!t in my eyes, no need to use a global :(

```
const softwaresSearch = document.getElementById('softwares-search');
if (softwaresSearch) {
  softwaresSearch.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    search = document.getElementById('softwares-search').value;
    var filtredSoftwares = softwares.filter(e => e.name.includes(search) || e.description.includes(search) );
    renderTable(filtredSoftwares);
  });
}

const renderTable = (softwares) => {
  Object.values(softwares).forEach(value=>{
    console.log(value);
  });
  // Todo build HTML table
}
```

Comment: `var results = softwaresSearch.addEventListener('keyup', maxwell)` why assign to `results`? `.addEventListener()` doesn't return anything. Nor does a `return` in a listener do much. I'm not really sure what this code is trying to achieve.

Comment: The `maxwell` function will be called when the user releases a key while typing into the "softwares-search" field. It won't return anything! However, the "maxwell" function can put the result of the software.filter(...) call into a variable (to be used later), or into an element on the page (to show it immediately in a table, or in a list etc.).

Comment: @VLAZ :( For me it is clear : I add a listener which is calling function maxwell to filter my JSON then returned the results to create a new table of filtred elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `addEventListener` function **always** returns `undefined`, so your `results` variable is undefined.
Returning from the callback function (maxwell) is also of no use.

You either need to do something with the data inside of your callback, or maybe pass the data to a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning I think you just need to replace the current array like this

```
const maxwell = () => {
  search = document.querySelector('#softwares-search').value;
  softwares = softwares.filter(row => row.name.includes(search) || row.description.includes(search));
}
```

And results is not needed:

```
const softwaresSearch = document.querySelector('#softwares-search');
if (softwaresSearch) {
  softwaresSearch.addEventListener('keyup', maxwell)
}
```

Comment: Better to declare a results variable inside that same function, as to not produce any side effects when messing with variables outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `softwareSearch.addEventListener` won't return anything, since that is an event listener, and does not return any value. It simply executes the function passed in the 2nd parameter. You could try doing this instead

```js
softwaresSearch.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        var results = maxwell();
        console.log(results);
});
```

What this would do is that, it would call your maxwell function when the keyup event, since that is what it looks you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please share all relevant code before posting a question, this code includes the variable "softwares" that exist outside what is visible to us.

Additionally, there are some issues with your code.

1. I don't understand your naming of the maxwell function. You should name functions as verbs, not anything else. A function is a machine that is doing something, and possibly returning something. It should be named to what it is doing.
2. On the second line, you say "search = ... ", but you didn't declare it as a variable.
3. You are returning something based on a value that isn't validated ('search' can be either undefined or a string value in this case), hence, your return will most likely just return undefined and not any value at all.
4. Your function can possibly not return anything at all since you are returning something within your if-statement. You can use a closure to always return something.
5. I would also suggest passing a search string as a variable to your function that should return a list based on the search query. Getting in the habit of short, concise functions with expected inputs/outputs, will make your code more readable and less error-prone and less likely to produce unwanted side-effects.
6. I don't know the rest of your code, but I don't recommend assigning variables in the global scope. Your "maxwell", "softwareSearch" variables both exist in the global space, unless you have wrapped them in another function block already (such as jquerys $(document).ready(() => { ...everything here is scoped })
7. You are getting the same element in two different places in your code.

Here is an updated code sample, but I can't test it since I don't know the rest of your code.

```
/* 
 * Executing the whole thing in this IIFE will make all variables declared inside here scoped to this block only, 
 * thus they can't interfere with other code you may write
 */

(() => {
    const listOfSoftwares = softwares; // --- get your softwares variable here somehow, I don't know where "software" comes from.

    // input element
    const search = document.querySelector('#softwares-search');

    /**
     * Filter search results
     * @param {string} query Search query
     * @returns {Array} The results array
     */
    const filterSoftwareSearchResults = (query) => {
        let results = [];

        results = listOfSoftwares.filter(software => software.description.includes(query) || software.title.includes(query))

        // Verify
        console.log(results); 
    
        // Should return array of results, even if empty
        return results; 
    }

    if (search) {
        search.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            filterSoftwareSearchResults(search.value) 
        })
    }
})()
```

Comment: This is all the code you need to view, softwares is a JSON available when page is loaded. Maxwell is not the final name function it is a joke with a friend (Maxweel is a trademark of coffee filter...

Comment: Alright, fair enough, but still, please give the proper details that is needed to assess your issue. I spent time answering your question and took note of other things I saw in your code, and I'm sure many others could have done that as well.

If you post a question, make your code as readable and detailed as possible. It is better that one person spends a little time writing a good question than 15 people spending time being confused by a badly formatted question!

Comment: I thought I was clear, thanx for the time spent for me :/

Comment: I have `fil_script.js:189 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined` where you chain the includes method

Comment: ah, my bad. I like to use a "matches" function myself, but I think it actually produced the error here. Sorry, didn't test the code. Updated the code to use same kind of check you did, should work.

Also, didnt mean to sound harsh, more as a pointer :) No worries

Comment: No worry ;) I made some javascript code since IE6 but not alldays (I work in a department University for student learning informatic and  I have multiple tasks : repairs, assist users, deploy, update servers, etc etc) Can't specialize into one thing and with the time (code web site or applications since 2000) it is always hard for me to follow new concepts like CSS Flex or Deploying RoR webapp with Mina etc , still learning :/